# Saint Nicholas's Airborne Gift Distribution: Can Biblatex/Biber respect mincrossrefs when using ids? Why do defunct entries resist removal?

Tags: biblatex, biber

Consider the following MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{incoll,
  author    =   {Claus, Santa},
  title     =   {The Aerodynamics of Modern the Modern Sleigh},
  pages     =   {34--98},
  crossref  =   {coll}}
@collection{collect,
  ids       =   {coll},
  title     =   {Airborne Gift Distribution: Technical Considerations},
  editor    =   {Nicholas, Saint},
  year      =   2013,
  publisher =   {Rudolph Press},
  address   =   {Greenland}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mincrossrefs=6]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{document}

\Textcite{incoll}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I would expect this to yield a bibliography with a single entry. However, I get two.

[image: one entry too many]

Is this another bug in the handling of `ids`? Or is this expected? How can I stop it without having to go through all my `.bib` files to remove the use of `ids` in the `crossref` of other entries?

Moreover, why is editing the `.bib` file to remove the use of `coll` in `incoll`, replacing it by `collect`, not sufficient to solve the problem after another compilation cycle? To resolve it, I have to remove the `.bcf`/`.bbl` files and force them to be rewritten. This is true even if I remove all references to either `coll` or `collect` from `incoll`. For example, even if I change the `.bib` file to

```
@article{incoll,
  author    =   {Claus, Santa},
  title     =   {The Aerodynamics of Modern the Modern Sleigh},
  pages     =   {34--98},
  year      =   2013,
  volume    =   99,
  journal   =   {Airborne Gift Distribution: Technical Considerations}}
@collection{collect,
  ids       =   {coll},
  title     =   {Airborne Gift Distribution: Technical Considerations},
  editor    =   {Nicholas, Saint},
  year      =   2013,
  publisher =   {Rudolph Press},
  address   =   {Greenland}}
\end{filecontents}
```

and rerun the sequence `pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex` a couple of times, my bibliography will include the `collect` entry forever. Only by manually removing the `bbl`/`bcf` and rerunning the sequence can I get rid of this.

I'm mystified by this behaviour: isn't the `.bcf` rewritten on the new run of `pdflatex`? And isn't the `.bbl` rewritten on the new run of `biber`? Provided no error prevents the files from being rewritten, why should they need to be manually deleted in order to expunge defunct entries? Are there any other cases I should be aware of where this may occur?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the case here because I didn't have a look, but there are some cases where it really is required to delete all temporary files when `biblatex` options were changes. (I think `defernumbers` can be such a case.) So I wouldn't worry too much about having to delete temporary files after a change to the `ids`. The other problem though is interesting, but I think at a Biber-level, so way above my pay grade.

Comment: @moewe I'm also more interested in the first problem. I was just surprised by the second, a bit. But the main one is the main one, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Maybe you want to bring this up on the Biber (or `biblatex`) bug tracker. It seems as though people here don't have that brilliant idea that leads to a solution. I suspect this is something for the Biber developer to take care of.

Comment: @moewe Thanks. https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/161

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug, fixed in Biber 2.8 DEV version.